# Why html buttons dynamically created by django cannot access my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

My Django application makes divs dynamically. Each div is a post of a blog post and also I have a like button on each div. Each button will automatically turn into unlike when a user clicks on it without reloading using javascript. I wrote a javascript function for this. Unfortunately, my javascript function works only the last post on a page (As I have pagination property).

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    // const colon = document.createElement('div');
    // colon.setAttribute('id','colon')
    // e.preventDefault()
    // const likebtn = document.createElement('button');
    // likebtn.setAttribute('class','likebtn btn btn-primary');
    // likebtn.setAttribute('class','likebtn');
    // document.querySelector('.card-footer').appendChild(likebtn);
    // document.querySelector('.likebtn').innerHTML = "Like";
    
    document.querySelector(`#likeform${posts_id}`).addEventListener('submit',(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        like_function();
        // return false;
    })
    // document.querySelector('.likepost').addEventListener('click', ()=> like_function('likepost'));
})



// let is_like = "{{is_like}}";
// let num_like = "{{num_like}}";

function like_function(){
    // document.createElement('button').innerHTML = "Love";
    // console.log("Updated!")
    fetch(`/like/${posts_id}`,{
        method:"POST",
        body : JSON.stringify({
            "is_like" : is_like,
            "num_like" : num_like,
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.is_like){
            console.log("function is liked");
            console.log(`${result.is_like} for post ${posts_id}`);
            let num_like = result.num_like;
            console.log(`Number of posts : ${num_like}`);
            document.querySelector(`#likebtn${posts_id}`).innerHTML = "Unlike";
            num_like = num_like + 1;
            console.log(`Number of posts : ${num_like}`);
            document.querySelector(`#num_of_likes_${posts_id}`).innerHTML = `${num_like} `
            // location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000")
        }
        else{
            console.log("function is unliked, back off!");
            console.log(`${result.is_like} for post ${posts_id}`);
            let num_like = result.num_like;
            console.log(`Number of posts : ${num_like}`);
            document.querySelector(`#likebtn${posts_id}`).innerHTML = "Like";
            num_like = num_like - 1;
            console.log(`Number of posts : ${num_like}`);
            document.querySelector(`#num_of_likes_${posts_id}`).innerHTML = `${num_like} `
            // location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000")
        }
    })
    
}

// function like_function(){
//     if (document.querySelector("#like").style.color == "blue"){
//         document.querySelector("#like").style.color = "red";
//     }else{
//         document.querySelector("#like").style.color = "blue";
//     }
// }
```

This is my full javascript code. Here I'm sharing my HTML template,

```html
<div id="posts" class="card">
            <ul class="card-body">
                {% for posts in page_view %}    
                    <li class="card"> 
                         <div class="card-header bg-success">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><a class="text-light" style="text-decoration: none;" href="{% url 'profile' posts.user.id %}">{{ posts.user }}</a></h5> 
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-light">{{ posts.timestamp }}</h6>
                         </div>
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <h3 class="card-text">{{ posts.post }}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="likeapost{{posts.id}}" class="card-footer">
                            {% if request.user in posts.likepost.all %}
                                <form action="{% url 'likepost' posts_id=posts.id %}" id="likeform{{posts.id}}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
                                    <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
                                    <button id="likebtn{{posts.id}}" class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Unlike</button>
                                </form>
                            {% else %} 
                                <form action="{% url 'likepost' posts_id=posts.id %}" id="likeform{{posts.id}}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
                                    <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
                                    <button id="likebtn{{posts.id}}" class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Like</button>
                                </form>
                            {% endif %}
                            <small id="num_of_likes_{{posts.id}}" class="num_of_likes">{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}</small>
                            
                            {% block script %} 
                                <script>
                                    posts_id = "{{ posts.id }}";
                                    is_like = "{{is_like}}";
                                    num_like = "{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}";
                                </script>
                                <script src="{% static 'network/controller.js' %}"></script>
                            {% endblock %}
                            <button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Comment</button>
                            <a href="{% url 'postpage' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">View Post</a>
                            {% if request.user.id is posts.user.id %}
                                <a href="{% url 'editpost' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Edit</a>
                               
                            {% endif %}
                            <!-- <div class="likepost"></div> -->
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% empty %}
                    <h6>No post availabel </h6>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>     
        </div>
```

This is my HTML template. All the buttons should work like [this](https://youtu.be/si8t9C4a-bQ),

Only this one button works perfectly, but others do not. [This is what happening.](https://youtu.be/n6rAP1bL1ys)
What should I do? I am about 90% done. Please help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not yet. I can't figure out where my mistake is! Only one button works perfectly but others don't.